# How do I keep elements in a frame justified to the right while keeping the entire frame coloured, regardless of the size of the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter so I'm a little lost in terms of grid layout. What I'm trying to do is have a logo sit in the bottom right corner of the window, and always be in that position no matter how big the window is. I have managed to position the logo no problem, but when I justify to the right, the frame becomes white on the left side of the elements. How do I keep this part Black as it is under the logo? Left justify fills the whole frame with black, but right justify only fills from the logo/text onward.

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuaXy.png)

Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# GUI attributes
root.title('Lantern')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.iconbitmap('iconrl.ico')

# main containers
topFrame = Frame(root, bg='#000000', width=800, height=100, pady=3)
center = Frame(root, bg='#181818', padx=3, pady=3)
btmFrame = Frame(root, bg='#000000', width=800, height=90, padx=10)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

topFrame.grid(row=0, sticky='ew')
center.grid(row=1, sticky='nsew')
btmFrame.grid(row=2, sticky='e')

# topFrame Widgets
rlLabel = Label(topFrame, text='Lantern ', font=('Verdana', 12), fg='red', bg='#000000', width=10)

# topFrame Layout
rlLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

# center Widgets
# center Layout
# btmFrame Widgets

powered = Label(btmFrame, text='Powered by: ', font=('Verdana', 12), fg='#FFF204', bg='#000000', width=15)
sLogo = PhotoImage(file='slogo.png')
sLogoLabel = Label(btmFrame, image=sLogo, bg='#000000')

# btmFrame Layout

powered.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
sLogoLabel.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e')


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change `btmFrame.grid(row=2, sticky='e')` to `btmFrame.grid(row=2, sticky='ew')`, so that the frame fills all the space horizontally.

Then add `btmFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to push the `powered` and `sLogoLabel` to the right of the frame.

Or you can use `pack()` on `powered` and `sLogoLabel`:

```
sLogoLabel.pack(side='right')
powered.pack(side='right')
```